# Classic editor does not functional

Tags: laravel, ckeditor5

I'm trying to include CKEditor5 in my code, following their official docs at https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html exactly. And yeah, it is shown up but the UI seems like not functional. I can't get the text bolded, and such...

Does someone has any idea?

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/12.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

...

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter post title" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="slug">Post slug</label>
                    <input type="text" name="slug" id="slug" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter post slug" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="body">Content</label>
                    <textarea name="body" id="editor"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" name="cover_image" id="cover_image" class="custom-file-input" />
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="cover_image">Choose cover image (optional)</label>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
...
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
```

Comment: This itself isn't that helpful. Have you checked with your developer console (DevTools on Chrome)?

Comment: It shows nothing in the console.

Comment: You could be having a javascript conflict with your app.js. Try removing that reference and check if it works.